# I would like to clone two input fields using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to create a form where the user might want to add two input fields dynamically, and this form is linked to the validate JQuery Plugin.

```
$('.addnote').on("click",function(){
    countnotes++;
    var newnote = $(".notes:first").clone();
    newnote.find('input:file').val("");
    newnote.find('input:text').val("");
    var oldindexinput = countnotes-2;
    var newindexinput = countnotes-1;
    var attachement = newnote.find('#Justificatif'+oldindexinput+'Attachment');

    attachement.attr('id','Justificatif'+newindexinput+'Attachment');
    attachement.attr('name','data[Justificatif]['+newindexinput+'][attachment]');
    var motif = newnote.find('#Justificatif'+oldindexinput+'Motif');

    motif.attr('id','Justificatif'+newindexinput+'Motif');
    motif.attr('name','data[Justificatif]['+newindexinput+'][motif]');
    newnote.find('input:text[readonly]');
    var firstnoteid = $(".notes:first").attr('id');
    newnote.attr('id','notes'+countnotes);
    newnote.attr('style','');
    newnote.insertBefore('#'+firstnoteid).hide();
    newnote.slideDown();

});
```

**Here is the Html code**

```
<input name="data[Justificatif][0][attachment]" type="text" readonly placeholder="Feuille de support"  required>

<input name="data[Justificatif][0][motif]" placeholder="Motif de dépenses" class="input-medium" maxlength="255" type="text" id="Justificatif0Motif" required>
```

The problem with my code is that it clones the validation status as well with the new input fields, and I want to get rid of that.

Thank you

[snapshot of the input fields cloned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU9d4.png)

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question if there were more information. For example, in the HTML of the page (viewed through something like firebug, that can handle dynamic HTML), what is the exact ID of the new input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, during jquery validation, `class='required'` is applied to the elements which are validation during form submit.
Given, the elements you are cloning does have `class='required'` defined, you may simply remove it after cloning.

```
var newnote = $(".notes:first").clone();
newnote.removeClass('required');
```

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/TP768/268/

Comment: If your problem is that the new field is also required, this should solve it for you. I had interpreted your question as being more "this field is being marked as invalid, even though it has valid content".

Comment: Your suggestion actually helped me to get rid of the validation status. I had to delete both classes 'state-error' and 'state-success' once cloned.
    
    newnote.find('.input.text.required').removeClass('state-error');
    newnote.find('.input.text.required').removeClass('state-success');

    newnote.find('.input.input-file').removeClass('state-error');
    newnote.find('.input.input-file').removeClass('state-success');

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts off the top of my head (based on a similar project I'm referencing):

- Can you confirm that the id of the new input field is definitely unique. I see you calling "newnote.attr('id','notes'+countnotes);", but can you confirm the html is changed correctly?
- If the id is unique, try unattaching and reattaching your validation engine. (In my code I kill everything and recreate my forms every time there's a change, then re-call jQuery($('form[name$="config_form"]')).validationEngine('attach');)